# Creating Apache Spark-powered "As Service" applications

Tags: client-server, webclient, apache-spark

The question is about the ways to create a Windows desktop-based and/or web-based application client that is able to connect and talk to the server containing Spark application (either local or on-premise cloud distributions) in the run-time.

Any language/architecture may work. So far, I've seen two things that may be a help in that, but I'm not so sure if they would be the best alternative and how they work yet:

1. Spark Job Server - https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver - defines a REST API for Spark
2. Hue - http://gethue.com/get-started-with-spark-deploy-spark-server-and-compute-pi-from-your-web-browser/ - uses item 1)

Any advice would be appreciated. Simple toy example program (or steps) that shows, e.g. how to build such client for simply creating Spark Context on a local machine and say reading text file and returning basic stats would be ideal answer!

Comment: Just FYI There is a big update coming up in Hue 3.8 (end of Q1 2015) that will simplify all of this

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look on how the guys at Adobe Research built their [spindle](https://github.com/adobe-research/spindle) platform. Personally I haven't investigated that in detail, but they are also providing "Spark query results as a service".

Comment: Thanks, this may be helpful in investigation